# Point a domain name to a DDNS?

Tags: dns

Basic question: How can I point a domain name to a DDNS record? CNAME? DNAME?

```
domainname.com DNAME something.no-ip.org
```

I mention a DNAME just in case so subdomain.domainname.com is also covered.

I imagine where I register my domain, I have DNS services so I can set that up there as well.

Can't really give more information than that for my question.

As you see no-ip.org is my DDNS provider so it is well known and not something weird or strange

Answer (score 2):

For *subdomains*, yes, either CNAME or DNAME would work exactly like in your example.

However, CNAME cannot be used alongside any other record type. Since the domain itself (the 'zone apex') *must* have SOA and NS records on it, that means it cannot also be a CNAME. (CloudFlare [used to allow this](https://blog.cloudflare.com/zone-apex-naked-domain-root-domain-cname-supp/) for a while, but it didn't work well.) See e.g. [[1]](http://joshstrange.com/why-its-a-bad-idea-to-put-a-cname-record-on-your-root-domain/), [[2]](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains),

That said, some DNS providers have their own solutions, usually a special record type like [ALIAS or ANAME](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#root-domain) which gets resolved at the provider's side and refreshed every now and then. CloudFlare calls this [CNAME flattening](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/).

Comment: I apoligize but there is too much explanation done. I would simply like to know if with a domain name register I can do this. I register a domainname.com or *.domainname.com and if I can point that to something.no-ip.org. If there are some that allow this and some that do not, please point it out so I know where to register my domain name.

Comment: @riahc3: I already gave a link to such a [list](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#root-domain).

Comment: your list was lost in the explanation. You could have said DNSimple, DNS Made Easy, easyDNS, CloudFlare, PointDNS and Zerigo all support what I want. Either way, I wanted the DNS services of my domain name register NOT get a ADDITIONAL DNS service that does this and pay more money. Bottom line: I have to ask my doman name register.

Answer (score 0):

No-IP doesn't allow for wildcarding on its free service. You won't be able to setup subdomains without paying for it. Furthermore, as far as I can tell they don't allow you to point to your own NS (Thus circumventing that limitation). I've been poking around for a new DDNS provider for these reasons...

I miss DynDNS Free...

Edit:

Misunderstood. You can absolutely point one domain to another using a CNAME DNS entry.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656009/how-to-overcome-root-domain-cname-restrictions

The above link talks about what you'd like to do. IIS and Apache both offer URL Rewriting which would likely be the better option but requires more work.

Comment: I mean subdomains on my domain name. hi.domainname.com, bye.domainname.com etc. all pointing to something.no-ip.org

Comment: @riahc3: For that you'd need a cname on `*.domain.com` – not a dname.

Comment: Corrrect, you'd need a CNAME entry for that.

Comment: The subdomain was just a curiosity. I want to know if I can do a domain name.

Comment: Absolutely. It's still just a CNAME.

Comment: @NathanialMeek So I can do what I want? Please post as a answer so I can mark you as the correct answer :)

Comment: Edited my original answer.

Comment: Should I check with domain name register if it is possible?